# Is std::call_once multi-processor safe?

Tags: c++11, thread-safety, multiprocessing

The [CPP Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) states `std::call_once` is thread safe:

> Executes the function f exactly once, even if called from several threads.

Will I need to use memory barriers when utilizing lazy initialization if the code runs on a machine with multiple physical processors (as opposed to a single processor with multiple cores)? For example:

```
static Foo& GetFooRef()
{
    static std::once_flag flag;
    static Foo foo;

    MEMORY_BARRIER();
    std::call_once(flag, []() {

        Foo f = ...;
        foo.swap(f);
    });

    MEMORY_BARRIER();
    return foo;
}
```

Where `MEMORY_BARRIER()` is

- `_ReadWriteBarrier()` for MSVC,
- `__asm__ __volatile__ ("" ::: "memory")` for GCC,
- `__memory_barrier()` for ICC, etc.

Comment: Yes, thread safety implies multiprocessor safety, if we are talking about shared memory model, and I think you are.

Comment: Thanks bolov. So I'm clear - there are no cache coherency problems when using `call_once`?

Comment: the hardware deals with cache-coherency problems. They are transparent to the software (I am 99% sure)

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't define or reference the term "multi-processor", so it is not possible to answer the question in the context of the standard.

Comment: Thanks n.m. "... it is not possible to answer the question in the context of the standard" - well, this is a real world problem whether the C++ committee want to acknowledge it or not :)

Comment: The standard addresses many problems without having to name them explicitly. This particular problem is addressed by defining the standard in such a way that an efficient implementation on a multiprocessor is possible. You may ask your compiler vendor whether or not their compiler complies with this or another piece of the standard. A non-multiprocessor-safe implementation of this function will render the implementation non-compliant.

Comment: `std::call_once` is available since C++11, but "magic" statics (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2660.htm) are also available since C++11. Perhaps it would be better to just use them instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is the whole point of `call_once`. Thread-safe means on the same or different processors, on an ordinary machine with shared memory.

Comment: Thanks Herb. "Thread-safe means on the same or different processors..." in the past, I seem to recall a distinction was sometimes made though I never really understood it. To me, being thread safe but not multi-processor safe (due to cache coherency issues) is kind of like being half pregnant.